# How to convert Unix Time to Human Readable in Integromat?

Tags: make.com

My preceding module in Integromat gives me an expiration date in UNIX time, which is 1640930400.

When I use the FormatDate function to convert this, I'm getting 12/31/1969 when I was expecting to get 12/31/2021. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead to first parse the date and then apply the desired formatting to get the results that you want,

```
{{formatDate(parseDate(1.date; "X"); "MM/DD/YYYY")}}
```

[image]